# What is a first and second order cone?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am aware of the definition of a cone set $C$.  $x_1, x_2 \in C$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2 \ge 0$

$$\theta_1x_1+\theta_2x_2 \in C$$

However, what is a first-order and second-order cone?

Specifically, relating to second order cone programming, why do we call the constraint

$$ \lVert Ax+b \rVert_2 \le c^Tx+d$$

a second order constraint and why do we call it a cone constraint?

Comment: This is a second order cone constraint as it contains quadratic terms in x from the euclidian $||.||_{2}$ norm.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I also don't fully understand why it's called a cone constraint in the first place, would you care to elaborate on that as well?

Comment: Because whenever the $x$ satisfies this inequality it will belong to a cone

Comment: Actually, @GeorgeDewhirst that is only true if $b=0$, $d=0$. In general, the set of $x$ that satisfies the constraint is _not_ a cone. The reason this is a conic constraint is that its of the form $(Ax+b,c^Tx+d)\in C$, where $C$ is the cone $\{(y,z)\,|\,\|y\|_2\leq z\}$.

Comment: fair play.......

Comment: @MichaelGrant Could you please give an example of an x that satisfies the constraint but is not in the cone? Also, could you elaborate on what you say "it is only true if $b=0, d=0$? 

Is there a decent textbook that you can recommend with a good chapter on cones?

Answer (score 1):

It's called the second order cone because it's defined by a quadratic equation rather than a linear one. This naming is consistent with a quadratic polynomials being of degree two while a linear polynomial is of degree one.

Comment: I also don't fully understand why it's called a cone constraint in the first place, would you care to elaborate on that as well?

Comment: @Rufus Linear cones and quadratic cones are both bundle of lines connecting points on the interior to a special convex subset of the cone. For a typical quadratic cone that's the single point at the "apex" of the cone. Informally linear cones are similar but have hyper-plane boundaries instead of hyper-circles.