# A cone through two circles on a sphere

Tags: geometry

In page 37 of Blaschke's *Vorlesungen Über Differentialgeometrie*, vol. III, when proving a theorem on Möbius transformations the author says *"Denn durch zwei Kugelkreise läßt sich bekanntlich immer ein Kegel zweiter Ordnung legen, ..."*. In a free translation:

"As is well-known, there is always a second-order cone through two circles on a sphere".

Although I know how to prove the above fact by interpreting the map of the sphere onto itself given by a central projection in terms of a Lorentzian reflection on the space $\mathbb{R}^4$ of homogeneous coordinates, I would be happy to see a more geometric argument which constructs the vertex of such a cone (let's say, some argument that Poncelet, or even Euclid, would find).

Comment: [+1] Interesting question.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez I think that it plainly means "defined by a quadratic equation" (see [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3449883/305862))

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Surely any two conics are projective. But by itself it doens't help since we seek for a projective map between the planes carrying the conics (actually circles) that is actually a central projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the plane passing through the centers of the sphere and of both circles. This plane intersects the circles at diameters $AB$ and $CD$. If lines $AC$ and $BD$ (or $AD$ and $BC$) meet at $V$, then $V$ is the vertex of the requested cone.

That's because triangles $VAB$ and $VCD$ are similar, hence the two circles are what Apollonius called two subcontrary sections of the cone ([Book 1, Proposition 5 in "The conics"](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonconics00apolrich/page/3/mode/1up)).

You'll have in general two solutions, with $V$ inside or outside the sphere.

[image]

EDIT.

Here's the proof (as given by Apollonius) that a subcontrary section to the base of a circular oblique cone is also a circle.

Let's consider then a cone of vertex $V$ and a circular base (see figure below). Diameter $AB$ of the base is chosen so that plane $VAB$ is perpendicular to the plane of the circle.

On triangle $VAB$ choose points $C$ (on $VA$) and $D$ (on $VB$) suche that $\angle VDC=\angle VAB$. The plane through $CD$ perpendicular to triangle $VAB$ cuts then the cone along a curve $CPD$ (which is called a subcontrary section of the cone). We want to show that this curve is a circle.

Indeed, consider any point $P$ on that curve and the plane through $P$ parallel to the base. That plane cuts the cone along a circle $GPI$, with diameter $GI$ lying on triangle $ABV$ and parallel to $AB$. Diameters $CD$ and $GI$ intersect at $H$: by construction $PH$ is perpendicular both to $CD$ and $GI$.

As $PGI$ is a circle, we have:
$$
PH^2=GH\cdot IH.
$$
But triangles $CGH$ and $DIH$ are similar (because
$\angle IDH=\angle VAB=\angle CGH$), hence
$$
GH:CH=DH:IH,\quad\text{that is:}\quad CH\cdot DH=GH\cdot IH.
$$
Comparing with the previous equality we then get:
$$
CH\cdot DH=PH^2.
$$
But this holds for any point $P$ on the curve, hence that curve is a circle, QED.

[image]

Comment: But aren't the cones considered by Apollonius circular cones, whereas here the cones we are after are in general elliptic ?

Comment: Besides, I deeply admire your knowledge of greek geometry !

Comment: @JeanMarie Apollonius considered circular oblique cones. See here: https://archive.org/details/treatiseonconics00apolrich/page/3/mode/1up

Comment: I made an animation with GeoGebra to show this: https://www.geogebra.org/m/rpuudvpa

Comment: Nice animation. I would be interested to understand your code for this figure (I am still fighting to have a better proficiency with Geogebra...). How can I have access to it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie From the three dots up-right -> Open in App. In the new page, the three-bar menu has an option to save as GeoGebra file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw, I just brought a complement to one of your answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765059/305862).